# EF 4.1 using custom type handling money

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I have been using a custom type for Money with my POCOs and tries to insert this to my database but it is *implicitly* thrown away by Entity Framework.

This is my code made simple;

My type;

```
public struct Money
{
    private static decimal _value;

    public Money(Decimal value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Money(Decimal value)
    {
        return new Money(value);
    }

    public static implicit operator decimal(Money value)
    {
        return _value;
    }
}
```

My object;

```
public class MyObject
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Money MyMoney { get; set; }
}
```

My context;

```
public class Data : DbContext
{
    public Data()
        : base("Data Source=.;Database=MyTest;Integrated Security=True")
    {}

    public DbSet<MyObject> MyObject { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<MyObject>()
            .Property(p => p.MyMoney).HasColumnName("MyMoney");

    }
}
```

When I use this code I get the following error.

> The property 'MyMoney' is not a
>   declared property on type 'MyObject'.
>   Verify that the property has not been
>   explicitly excluded from the model by
>   using the Ignore method or
>   NotMappedAttribute data annotation.
>   Make sure that it is a valid primitive
>   property.

I guess the problem is the last sentence.... Then, what is a valid primitive property? Is there any other way to take care of this?

Comment: Per,

Maybe you can helpe me: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6794565/828162

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this went to be my solution.

```
public class MyObject
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Money MyMoney { get { return (Money)MyMoneyInternal; } set { MyMoneyInternal = (decimal)value; } }
    private decimal MyMoneyInternal { get; set; }
}
```

To be able to read that private property I created a property extension as below. Since some of my properties of type Money is Nullable I had to take care of that as well.

```
public static class PropertyExtensions
{
    public static PrimitivePropertyConfiguration Property<TClass, TProperty>(this EntityTypeConfiguration<TClass> etc, string propertyName)
        where TClass : class
        where TProperty : struct
    {
        PrimitivePropertyConfiguration returnValue;
        Type type = typeof(TClass);

        var propertyInfo = type.GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(type, "xyz");
        MemberExpression memberExpression = Expression.Property((Expression)parameterExpression, propertyInfo);

        if (IsNullable(memberExpression.Type))
        {
            returnValue = etc.Property((Expression<Func<TClass, TProperty?>>)Expression.Lambda(memberExpression, parameterExpression));
        }
        else
        {
            returnValue = etc.Property((Expression<Func<TClass, TProperty>>)Expression.Lambda(memberExpression, parameterExpression));
        }

        return returnValue;
    }

    private static bool IsNullable(Type type)
    {
        bool result;

        if (type.IsGenericType)
        {
            var genericType = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
            result = genericType.Equals(typeof(Nullable<>));
        }
        else
        {
            result = false;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

And then I could use that to read my private property.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyObject>()
            .Property<MyObject, decimal>("MyMoneyInternal").HasColumnName("MyMoney");
```

Thank you Steve for taking me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

You could take of it by explicitly mapping a decimal property and only exposing the `Money` Property to callers:

```
public class MyObject
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    protected decimal MyMoney { get; set; }
    public Money MyMoneyStruct 
    { 
        get { return (Money)this.MyMoney; } 
        set { this.MyMoney = (decimal)value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea. Unfortunatelly code-first doesn't map protected and private fields. To overcome this you must use nested `EntityConfiguration` in each entity which makes your entity project EF dependent.

Comment: @Ladislav, thanks, I didn't know that.  That seems like kind of an oversight as I would expect it to allow protected fields.  Oh well.  I suppose one could always expose both, or use EntityConfiguration as you described.

Comment: @Steve: You can also use `internal` fields and play with it. There are two problems: default mapping maps only public members and both `EntityConfiguration` and `OnModelCreating` use fluent API which is limited to accessibility of members.

Comment: Yes, I did think this would be a possible way even though not optimal but I got stuck with the limitation of scope. Any other idea? I got one myself, making my struct a class instead and use ComplexTypeConfiguration. I haven't tried it yet but i will.

Comment: Ok, I have tried making it a class instead and it does give me a solution for my problem with my custom type. Though introducing other problems with naming of my fields in database, ie MyMoney_value. Therefore **I go for using Steves solution but with a public decimal named EFMyMoney**.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have transformed your "Money" in a Complex class; which would make the exposed properties in-line in your database.  With only the Decimal property, it would look like Money_Value (given you expose Value as a property).  Let's say you add "Currency" as a string to the class.  You would then have also Money_Currency in the database.

To declare to EF that your class is a Complex type, just annotate it with [ComplexType()].

To get the best of Struct + ComplexType, you could even use both at the time : the complex type using the struct internally (the ComplexType just being a wrapper).